# setting background to color reference from attrs.xml crashes

Tags: android, xml, android-styles

I've defined a color in my theme like following:

*attrs.xml*

```
<attr name="defaultTextColor" format="color|reference" />
```

*styles.xml*

```
<style name="BaseLightTheme" parent="@style/Holo.Theme.Light">
<item name="defaultTextColor">@color/primary_text_holo_light</item>
...
</style>

<style name="BaseDarkTheme" parent="@style/Holo.Theme">
<item name="defaultTextColor">@color/primary_text_holo_dark</item>
...
</style>
```

Whenever I use this for text colors, simply using `android:textColor="?defaultTextColor"` works fine. I want to use this color for a views background, but this crashes the app... Why? How can I solve that?

This just crashes:

```
<View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?defaultTextColor" />
```

**Edit: logcat added**

Here's my logcat for this error (Line 19 is the line of the above meantioned view):

```
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater._createView(LayoutInflater.java:262)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:470)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:316)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:604)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:422)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:372)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:367)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at com.mf.androfit.fragments.WorkoutFragment$CardioViewFragment.onCreateViewHandler(WorkoutFragment.java:865)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at com.mf.activitylibrary.fragments.BaseFragment.onCreateView(BaseFragment.java:185)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.support.v4.app._HoloFragment.onCreateView(_HoloFragment.java:124)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:928)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1105)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1461)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at com.mf.pagermanager.MFragStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(MFragStatePagerAdapter.java:170)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15696)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at org.holoeverywhere.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:877)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at org.holoeverywhere.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:956)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15696)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4851)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15696)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4851)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15696)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4851)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15696)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4851)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at org.holoeverywhere.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:452)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at org.holoeverywhere.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:784)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at org.holoeverywhere.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:956)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15696)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.support.v4.widget.MySlidingPaneLayout.onMeasure(MySlidingPaneLayout.java:523)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15696)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:639)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15696)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4851)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at org.holoeverywhere.widget.WindowDecorView.onMeasure(WindowDecorView.java:113)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15696)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4851)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15696)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at org.holoeverywhere.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:877)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at org.holoeverywhere.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:956)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15696)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4851)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-18 11:12:05.654: E/ACRA(8006):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl
```

Comment: post your logcat then

Comment: did so... I just get an `InflateException`...

Comment: In L they fixed an issue where you could not use attribute references for color drawables. What version are you running on? It should work on api 21. Unfortunately you can't use attribute references for colors on earlier versions.

Comment: I'm personally using v20... but it's useless if the function does not get integrated in the support library. At least for me. Thsnks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can simply define a background of a View through an attribute. 
In order to do that you will need to create a custom view.

You can find more info [here](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html).

A simple example would be to create a separate Java class in your src directory:

```
public class SuperView extends View { 

//You set all background attributes through your java code. 
}
```

After that you go to your layout.xml and add your custom view as such:

```
<my.application.SuperView 
    android:...../>
```

And you can add some additional common attributes for that view inside of xml.